# Why does my android app have a maximum RAM limit as 64 MB?

Tags: android, crash, virtual-machine, max, ram

I'm developing an android app that has a lot of bitmaps that uses a lot of RAM. My question is that when I keep my app running for a long time and the ram usage exceeds 64 MB, the app crashes with an "OUT OF MEMORY ERROR, VM won't let us allocate ... etc".

While other apps such as facebook reaches 200 MB ram sometimes without any crashes and with a very fast performance. My device is Galaxy S II.

and please notice that my question is not about reducing the memory usage, it's about the difference in memory limit between my app and other apps.

Thanks.

Comment: I speak ignorantly, but I really doubt facebook uses 200MB of ram.

Comment: Open it, and keep scrolling down for more news feeds for couple of minutes and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a limit on the amount of memory that an application can use... Used to be 32MB... There might be a permission that you can change to request more memory, in the same way that you can request hardware acceleration. From a quick google android:largeHeap="true" might be your answer... Also Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory(); might help? [This link](http://blog.javia.org/how-to-work-around-androids-24-mb-memory-limit/) was also interesting...

Comment: Am really tempted to write a test app to get past that limit - let me know if you find an answer!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. looks like the right answer but unfortunately I won't be able to use it since it's supported by API 11+ while I'm targeting API 8+

Comment: @0909EM that's simply not true, the memory limit is given by the brand and there a lot of different setup for different devices out there.

Comment: you used largeHeap? Umm... Could you go Native in your app? I'm not sure if that link is any help or whether going Native would help at all...

Comment: @Ken Ahh... yes, the memory limit is dependent on the device! Good point well made! I was using a Nexus S hence my 32MB limit... but your right that limit will vary depending on device

Comment: @Ken ,, its true that the memory is dependent on the device, but my question was that my same device force closing my app after exceeding 64 MB while other apps takes 150 MB and 200 MB ..

Comment: @user1621900 if you are experiencing this kind of problems the only reliable source is `adb logcat`

Answer (score 0):

The amount of memory that the vm is reserving for each application is not part of the Android ecosystem and can't be determined, it's part of the configuration given by the manufacturer.

Usually the last word about the memory size for each vm is given by the file `build.prop`.

Do not use the NDK trick if you do not know what are you doing.